# Char to String assistance

Tags: java

The error im getting is on Line 35 and it says "method english in class Project1 cannot be applied to given types. I don't understand and any help would be greatly appreciated. I think that I need to switch the variable type but I don't exactly know how. By the way I am new to java and trying to learn as fast as I can!

```
public class Project1
{
public static void main( String [] args )
{
    System.out.println();
    choice();

}
    public static void choice()
{
    int user_choice = 0; 
    user_choice = Input.getInt("Enter 1 if you want to change English to Morse code, and enter 2 to change Morse code to English");
    if(user_choice == 1)
    {
    String output = new String();
    String inital = new String();
    inital = english_to_morse();

    for( int k = 0; k < inital.length(); k++)
    {
        output += morse(inital.charAt( k ));
    }

        System.out.print(output);

    }
    if(user_choice == 2)
    {
    String output2 = new String();
    String inital2 = new String();
    inital2 = english_to_morse();

    for( int k = 0; k < inital2.length(); k++)
    {
        output2 += english(inital2.charAt( k ));///the error is here
    }

        System.out.print(output2);
    }
}

public static String english_to_morse() 
{
  String user_input = new String();

  user_input = Input.getString("Enter a phrase and I'll convert it to Morse Code");

  return user_input.toLowerCase();
}

public static String morse_to_english() 
{
  String user_input = new String();

  user_input = Input.getString("Enter a phrase in Morse Code and I'll convert it to English");

  return user_input.toLowerCase();
}

public static String morse(char letter)
{
    String output = new String();
    char[] alphabet_numbers = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ' ' };
    String morse_code[] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "|" };

    for( int j = 0; j < alphabet_numbers.length; j++ )
    {
        if (alphabet_numbers[j]==letter)
        {
            output = morse_code[j];
        }
    }
    return output + " ";
}   
public static String english(String letter)
{
    String output = new String();
    String alphabet_numbers[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", " " };
    String morse_code[] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "|" };

    for( int j = 0; j < morse_code.length; j++ )
    {
        if (morse_code[j]==letter)
        {
            output = alphabet_numbers[j];
        }
    }
    return output + " ";
}
```

}

Comment: Note: we don't know what the line 35 is. If you could, in the future, copy/paste the error message and indicates the line which cause the problem that would be helpful. Also look at the signature of `public static String english(String letter)` and with what argument you calls it. And see also [How do I compare Strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Compare the type of the variable you are passing into the method to the one the method is expecting in its declaration. They need to match; that error says they don't.

Comment: i said where the error was now with a comment

Comment: @user3474526 Look at the signature of the english method and with what parameters you call it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly convert `char` into String. Use `String.valueOf()` for this.

You had this line where your method `english()` accepts `String` as parameter, but you were passing `char` to it.

```
output2 += english(inital2.charAt( k ));
```

But it should be:

```
output2 += english(String.valueOf(inital2.charAt( k )));
```

Comment: @user3474526 we everybody are :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `english` method takes a String as an argument.  The call, `output += english(inital.charAt( k ));`, attempts to give it a char as input.  You may want to use `inital.substring(k, k+1)` instead of `inital.charAt(k)` to provide a one character String as an argument, instead of a char.

Comment: You might need to trace through your code a bit to make sure all the functions do the right thing.